# Custom User/Password Authentication in WCF service exposed by SOAP and REST endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service that needs some authentication functionality

- The service is exposed by a SOAP endpoint and a REST one. (i.e. the authentication mechanism should be usable from both types of clients)
- I have custom user/password authentication on the back end.
- I need the credentials to be passed from the client in plaintext, i.e. unencrypted (service runs in corporate VPN, password is already hashed).

What's the most elegant way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For username+password authentication, current recommended way is to use UserNameSecurityTokenHandler:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.usernamesecuritytokenhandler.aspx

You need System.IdentityModel which is newest version, do not mistake it for Microsoft.IdentityModel.

It works great with SOAP when you're able to generate proxy classes on the client side. You simply have to supply credentials to your client proxy class and handle the logic on the server side via the mentioned token handler.

I would strongly suggest this blog to use as a reference, just search for blog comments that contain word WCF. Dominick is one of the top experts in the field.

http://www.leastprivilege.com/